agrupe uno datos, deseo sacar promedio para cada grupo en SQL
Estoy apenas aprendiendo SQL, estoy practicando con un conjunto de datos correspondientes a prestamos bancarios, la tabla muestra el nivel de educación de cada solicitante (secundaria, profesional, maestría, doctorado) así como el monto de crédito solicitado.
Usé GROUP BY para agrupar los datos según el nivel de educación, sin embargo, quiero sacar el promedio de monto de dinero solicitado para cada grupo, es decir cuanto dinero en promedio solicitaron los de secundaria, los de profesional etc.
Sé que se usa AVG pero no se como decirle que solo me promedie por grupo y no en general toda la columna.
Esto es lo que llevo :
SELECT
  person_education,
  COUNT(*) AS education_level,
FROM 
  `loan.loan_approval`
GROUP BY
  person_education


Cuando digas que sabes usar AVG, incluye el uso dentro de la consulta, a pesar que sea erroneo el resultado.

Estás en lo correcto. Simplemente usa la función AVG(columna_monto) como si se tratara de una nueva columna de datos, el resto déjalo tal como lo tienes hasta ahora.
SELECT 
    person_education, 
    COUNT(*) AS education_level,
    AVG(loan_amount) AS average_loan_amount
FROM 
    loan.loan_approval
GROUP BY 
    person_education;


muchas gracias, por tu valiosa ayuda.  sin embargo, me pregunto, cómo puedo obtener la suma total de dinero solicitado (loan_amnt)  para cada grupo.  ejemplo, los  profesionales solicitaron xxx cantidad de dinero,  los de secundaria xxx cantidad.  sigo trabajando en ello..

nuevamente muchas gracias.  quise hacer la suma por categorias y cro que estaba complicando las cosas mas de lo normal.   al final me quedó asi (para la suma, no para el promedio):  SELECT
person_education,
COUNT (*) AS education_level,
SUM (loan_amnt)  AS avg_loan_amnt
FROM plasma-bounty-436601-n6.loan.loan_approval
GROUP BY
person_education;
